# Define route that matches file on disk

Tags: f#, nancy

I'm trying to decorate some of the files in the public directory by wrapping them in template.

Sample filesystem structure:

```
project_root\
    file_i_want_to_decorate.html
    file_that_should_be_just_downloadable.zip
```

The route `/{path*}` just captures all the files. Not good.

So my idea was to use custom matcher:

```
type ContentRouteSegmentConstraint() =
    inherit RouteSegmentConstraintBase<string>()
    let root = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROJECT_ROOT")        
    override x.Name with get() = "content"
    override x.TryMatch(``constraint``, segment, matchedValue) =
        matchedValue <- segment
        File.Exist(segment)
```

And add route `/{path*:content}`. Well, it works, but in a way that only the first segment is passed to the function. And even if it is called with `/index`, the parameter `"path"` in the dynamic dictionary is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is incorrect approach. Instead of matching function for the segment the route filtering function should be used as follows:

```
Get["/{path*}", (fun (context) -> context.Request.Url.Path |> content.CanServe)] <- fun ...
```